# Area51 Stats Error?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Checked both FF and Chrome, only to find some very odd stats being displayed on the Area 51 Joomla Proposal site:

[image]

I've circled in red the incorrect sections. Not sure why this is happening but can anyone else confirm this problem? If someone already hasn't by tonight, I will flag this error on Meta StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I am seeing. Probably there was a temporary error.

[image]

Comment: Ahh yes the error seems to be fixed for me now too.

Comment: Yes, this was fixed shortly before you checked; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234383/who-borked-the-area-51-stats, /cc @Lodder